# BoletoPHP: Problema ao gerar boleto do banco do brasil

Tags: php, boleto

Estou usando o projeto do github BOLETOPHP para gerar boletos do Banco do Brasil, então eu passei todos os dados necessários para gerar o boleto, como valor, data vencimento, conta, agencia, etc...

ai quando eu clico no botão de visualizar o boleto, ele vem tudo certinho, com o valor correto, conta, agencia... No entanto, quando eu fui tentar pagar o boleto pelo internet banking, aparece este erro: "Código de barra com DV Geral inválido".

Link do Boleto gerado: https://goo.gl/jZ3dSY

Imagem do Erro no Internet Banking do BB: https://goo.gl/zh92my

Imagem do Erro no Internet Banking do ITAÚ: https://goo.gl/a02fLK

Alguém poderia me ajudar, por favor...

Comment: Ué, você fala que banco itau funcionou? mas na imagem tem erro.

Comment: o que eu quis dizer é que o boleto do banco do itaú funcionou... o da imagem é o boleto do banco do brasil sendo testado no  internet banking do itaú...

Comment: Você deve seguir a documentação do Banco do Brasil e verificar na sua classe como é gerado o código de barras, assim você vai conseguir identificar pq o DV está saindo errado. Tem outra biblioteca de boletos também, caso você queira testar que é a OpenBoleto, do OpenBoleto, eu tenho os arquivos atualizados de vários bancos. Link da documentação BB: http://www.bb.com.br/docs/pub/emp/empl/dwn/Doc5175Bloqueto.pdf